# Query shared fields on "Work Items and Direct Links"

Tags: tfs, sprint

So I am trying to write a query that will show me completed bugs, of completed PBIs, that were handled within the same sprint. In other words, bugs we introduced with new functionality, but also closed before finishing the Iteration.

The issue is the hard reference to Iteration Path. What I would like is a variable like @ThisIteration, and I would place it both of the highlighted spots. This way I could return all of the Bugs and PBIs that were resolved with in the iteration for all time.

I assume this just doesn't exist within TFS Queries, so I am looking for work arounds, or clever solutions, like WIQL, etc.

Thanks,
Devin

[image]

Comment: Your description confused me, what that mean for the `shared fields` here? And `The issue is the hard reference to Iteration Path` You can specific the iteration path directly... why it's an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement: "`write a query that will show me completed bugs, of completed PBIs, that were handled within the same sprint`"

The query you created should works.  For the Iteration Path we can only use the macro `@CurrentIteration` in on-premise TFS. In VSTS you can use the `@CurrentIteration +/- n` to  offset the iteration. Please see [Query macros or variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=vsts#query-macros-or-variables) and [Query for items based on a sliding window of team iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=vsts#query-for-items-based-on-a-sliding-window-of-team-iterations) for details.

> **Note**
>
> Feature availability: The @CurrentIteration +/- n macro is supported
>   for VSTS only, and only when run from the web portal.

Besides, you need to adjust/modify the query based on the Bugs working as.

- If `Bugs are managed with requirements`, then the Bugs and PBIs are
  in the same level. So you can use `Board Column` field to filter...
- If `Bugs are managed with tasks`, then the Bugs and PBIs are not in the
  same level. Filter by `Board Column` will not work. So you need to use `State` field to filter...

WIQL would be the same...

[image]